# Offset Timer starts

Tags: c#

Hi new to the site so I apologize if my question is not properly formatted

If i have two events that need to alternate every 2 seconds (one is ON the other is OFF), how can i delay the start of one of the timers for the 2 second offset?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Timer aTimer = new Timer();
        Timer bTimer = new Timer();

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        bTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEventb);

        // Set the Interval to 4 seconds 
        aTimer.Interval = 4000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        bTimer.Interval = 4000;
        bTimer.Enabled = true;


        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
    // raised. 
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The status is on {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }
    private static void OnTimedEventb(object source, ElapsedEventArgs b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The state is off {0}", b.SignalTime);
    }
```

So I basically want the ON event to happen when the program starts, then 2 seconds later have the OFF event fire and so on

using vs 2012 console app but I will be using in windows forms program

Comment: Can you have just one timer with 2000ms interval and alternate between ON and OFF ?

Comment: Yeah of course, I just wasnt sure how to differentiate between the ON and OFF if its on one timer

Comment: For On and Off, just have a boolean field; say on is true and off is false and flip it at the end of the timer event.

Comment: The timer event is its own function though so the bool has to be declared within it to keep scope? And id have to initialize it as true or false to start with right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class level bool called `IsOn`, for example, and toggle that. You only need one timer to do this as `true` would mean it's on and `false` would mean it's off.

```
private static bool IsOn = true; //default to true (is on)
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Timer aTimer = new Timer();


    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);        

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds 
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;    


    Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}


// Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
// raised. 
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    IsOn = !IsOn;
    Console.WriteLine("The status is {0} {1}", IsOn.ToString(), e.SignalTime);
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I was trying to declare the bool out at the class level and I think i was just doing it wrong? I dunno, but thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Class level is right but maybe you didn't make it static, so it was inaccessible within the static method.